# Can my PyTorch forward function do additional operations?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, autograd

Typically a `forward` function strings together a bunch of layers and returns the output of the last one. Can I do some additional processing after that last layer before returning? For example, some scalar multiplication and reshaping via `.view`?

I know that the autograd somehow figures out gradients. So I don’t know if my additional processing will somehow screw that up. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[pytorch](/questions/tagged/pytorch) tracks the gradients via the [computational graph](https://jdhao.github.io/2017/11/12/pytorch-computation-graph/) of the *tensors*, not through the functions. As long as your tensors has [`requires_grad=True`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.requires_grad_) property and their [`grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.Tensor.grad) is not `None` you can do (almost) whatever you like and still be able to backprop.
As long as you are using pytorch's operations (e.g., those listed in [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html) and [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html)) you should be okay.

For more info see [this](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html#autograd-mechanics).

For example (taken from [torchvision's VGG implementation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/models/vgg.html#vgg11)):

```py
class VGG(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, features, num_classes=1000, init_weights=True):
        super(VGG, self).__init__()
        #  ...

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.features(x)
        x = self.avgpool(x)
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1)  # <-- what you were asking about
        x = self.classifier(x)
        return x
```

A more complex example can be seen in [torchvision's implementation of ResNet](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/models/resnet.html#resnet18):

```
class Bottleneck(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inplanes, planes, stride=1, downsample=None, groups=1,
                 base_width=64, dilation=1, norm_layer=None):
        super(Bottleneck, self).__init__()
        # ...

    def forward(self, x):
        identity = x

        out = self.conv1(x)
        out = self.bn1(out)
        out = self.relu(out)

        out = self.conv2(out)
        out = self.bn2(out)
        out = self.relu(out)

        out = self.conv3(out)
        out = self.bn3(out)

        if self.downsample is not None:    # <-- conditional execution!
            identity = self.downsample(x)

        out += identity  # <-- inplace operations
        out = self.relu(out)

        return out
```